# Strong signed NAudio.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, naudio

Does somebody have the Strong signed NAudio.dll?

Because I am bulding an application that requires the NAudio to be strong signed.

Error Assembly 'NAudio.dll' must be strong signed in order to be marked as a prerequisite.

Comment: Don't mark an assembly like this as a prerequisite, it isn't going to be installed on the user's machine.  Simply publish it with the rest of your executables.

Answer (score 1):

That, in fact, is a deployment error message. It means that ClickOnce-Deployment will check whether an assembly is installed in the target computer's GAC before running your application.

This is often wanted, for example when all computers within a company have a standard setup that includes an oracle client, MQ Client,...

If you do not deploy via ClickOnce, but rather via XCopy, your application will plainly throw an exception at startup if NAudio is neither in the execution dir nor in the GAC (where, lacking a strong name, it can't be).

Since NAudio.dll is a CodePlex project, you may deploy it along with your app and don't have to install it on all target machines seperately. Open your Project Settings, go to the "publish" Tab, click on "Application Files", locate NAudio and set its publish status to "Include". For that to work, you also have to make sure your reference to NAudio has "Copy Local" set to true.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's open source, you can download source, and [sign it yourself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123.aspx).